# Adding logic to a User Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm creating a simple User Control with three properties. For simplicity let's assume these are A, B and C. Moreover C = A + B. I want to display all of them in TextBoxes (A, B - User Editable, C - read only). Whenever a user modifies A or B, the value of C should be updated.

I've already created Dependency Properties for A and B in MyControl.xaml.cs file.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(double),
            typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0));

    public double A
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(double),
            typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0));

    public double B
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(BProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BProperty, value); }
    }
```

My question is: what shall I do with C and where its definition should be kept ? Should the logic be coded inside a control or maybe it's a user's responsibility to remember about the relationship between the properties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare another `DependencyProperty` for `C` in the `UserControl` and add property change handlers to your `A` and `B` properties to update the value of `C` when their values change. This should do the job:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(double),
    typeof(MyControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnAOrBPropertyChanged));

public static readonly DependencyProperty BProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(double),
    typeof(MyControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnAOrBPropertyChanged));

public static void OnAOrBPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, 
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    dependencyObject.SetValue(CProperty, (double)dependencyObject.GetValue(AProperty) +
        (double)dependencyObject.GetValue(BProperty));
}
```

You might like to view the [Read-Only Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754044.aspx) page on MSDN for help with declaring a read-only `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: Thanks ! That's exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make another dependency property for C also

You can try this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(double),
            typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnAorBChange));

        public double A
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(AProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("B", typeof(double),
                typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnAorBChange));

        public double B
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(BProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("C", typeof(double),
           typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        public double C
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(CProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void OnAorBChange(DependencyObject obj,
           DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var obj1 = obj as MyControl;
            obj1.C = obj1.A + obj1.B;
        }
```

I assume you did the proper binding :)